# how to cast integer to float in an ogrinfo sql statement?

Tags: sql, ogr

I have a shapefile for which I would like to add the values in a column.
As the sum exceeds the capacity of an integer, I need to cast values to a float.
I tried the following:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT sum(cast(POP as float(10,0))) FROM Settlement_points" Settlement_points.shp
```

`ogrinfo` returns error messages like:

```
ERROR 1: Invalid index : -1
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
OGRFeature(Settlement_points):0
  SUM_FIELD_1 (Real) = 0
```

1. How can I correct my sql statement?
2. What is actually processing the sql statment in `ogrinfo`; are there some limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno,

I don't know what your workflow is, but you can do it with the ogr tools in two steps:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT cast(POP as float(10,0)) FROM Settlement_points" sp_float.shp Settlement_points.shp

ogrinfo -sql "SELECT sum(POP) FROM sp_float" sp_float.shp
```

You could also use ogr2ogr in your second command to write the values to the shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for your 2 lines solutions! Nathan W (below) explains why it is not possible to do it in a single command.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on ogr sql page

> While the CAST operator can be applied anywhere in an expression,
>   including in a WHERE clause, **the detailed control of output field
>   format is only supported if the CAST operator is the "outer most"
>   operators on a field in the field definition list**. In other contexts
>   it is still useful to convert between numeric, string and date data
>   types.

So it looks you can't nest it inside the SUM function.  OGR SQL also doesn't support using a SELECT inside the FROM which would have been my next pick of style.

You are going to have to write out a new file with the POP column as float or upload you data into something like spatialite/sqlite to give you more power.

Comment: Nicely done Nathan!  I just figured the same thing out.  The cast stuff works nicely.  His errors were 'Invalid indes : -1'

Comment: Yeah I get the same error if I nest the CAST in the SUM

Comment: Many thanks for your detail answer! I should have search more on ogr pages...